# How to configure gdrive for deja-dup?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, backup, deja-dup, google-drive

Currently using **Kubuntu 18.04**. I am trying to set up deja-dup to backup my files to my Google Drive. I have already added my google accounts and can access my files on Google Drive through dolphin.

But I can't seem to select GDrive as my backup destination in deja-dup. Below is the error message I get.

[image: deja-dup]

Answer (score 1):

Configure Deja-Dup for automatic backups to remote Google Drive

1. Add Google account

   - KDE [instructions found on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLEuIbwdfSc)
   - Gnome: `[Apps Menu] > Settings > Online Accounts > Google`
2. Mount Google Drive (automatically on login)

   - KDE: follow above instructions
   - Gnome: `[Apps Menu] > Settings > Startup Applications > Add`

     1. `Name: Mount Google Drive`
     2. `Command: sh -c 'gio mount google-drive://<username>@gmail.com'`
3. Configure Deja-Dup for automatic backups

   > Open `Deja-Dup`, select your Google Drive account in `Storage Location`, name the folder, and enable automatic backups.

Comment: I followed the kde instructions but deja-dup is still not being able to identify the online account. I read somewhere that deja-dup relies on gnome-online-accounts. But gnome-control-center is not working in kde neon

Comment: It's a smart workaround but that's not technically a solution to "configuring a gdrive to deja-dup"